# How to change the order of the Front Page so it doesn't appear first

Tags: pages, navigation, order

I have a Portal page and also a Home page. The Portal page is very basic and has a handful of links linking to different systems, one of the links leads to the Home page of WordPress. I want the Portal page to be listed as #1 in the navigation and the Home page (Front page) to be listed as #2. Wordpress seems to ignore the Order field in the page options if the page is designated as the Front Page (designated via Settings --> Reading --> Front page displays --> Static Page).

Is there a way to have a page other than the front page in the order position #1 in the navigation?

Comment: This varies by theme, and by the type of navigation your theme uses. Does it automatically list pages? Does it use a custom menu? Or some other form of navigation? The homepage link may be hard-coded in your theme, which would require you to make a child theme, or it might be something simple to swap out such as updating a theme setting or a custom menu.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll dig into the theme files and have a look. I am fairly new to Wordpress but I am a programmer with experience in PHP.

Comment: FYI I am using the Vantage theme https://siteorigin.com/theme/vantage/

Comment: Looks like Vantage has the home link hard-coded in /parts/masthead.php. You could create a child theme - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/ - you really only need style.css to identify the theme and the files you're going to override, which would be /parts/masthead.php, you don't even need functions.php as the tutorial suggests unless you want to add or change other theme functionality.

Comment: Okay so I created a child theme and it's working fine, I created the folder, functions.php, screenshot.png, and style.css. Looked into the source for the theme and I found the line of code the spits out the navigation bar in file /wp-content/themes/vantage/parts/menu.php.  This is the code <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'link_before' => '<span class="icon"></span>' ) ); ?>  I had a look for wp_nav_menu and found it in the theme's functions.php file and I'm unsure where to go after this. register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'vantage' ),
 ) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @WebElaine for the tips about using a child theme. I found the code that put the `Home` link first. The file was located in `/wp-content/themes/vantage/inc` and file `extras.php`

```
function vantage_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```

Had to change `$args['show_home'] = false;` to `false`.